# Ordering the result from database starting from the number 1

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, mysqli

I need to order the result I get from the database starting from the number 1, all the way to how many rows there are. How do I do that?

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE section = '1'
```

**Result:**

```
id | name | section
56 | Adam | 1
57 | Mary | 1
58 | Kate | 1
```

**Need Result:**

```
index | id | name | section
1     | 56 | Adam | 1
2     | 57 | Mary | 1
3     | 58 | Kate | 1
```

P.S: No, index is not a column name in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a user-defined variable:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 `index`, t.*
FROM tableName t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
WHERE t.section = '1'
```

Comment: Very nice. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

As you query the rows and loop through the results, just use the loop index+1:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($rows); $i++)
{
    echo ($i+1)." | ".$rows[$i]["id"]." | ".$rows[$i]["name"]." | ".$rows[$i]["section"];
}
```

Or a foreach loop and a counter:

```
$counter = 1;

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    echo $counter." | ".$row["id"]." | ".$row["name"]." | ".$row["section"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To order the data coming out of mysql, add to the end of your select statement `ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC` so change your select statement to be:
    `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE section = '1' ORDER BY ID ASC`

In your php code where you are stepping through lines of data to display, simply add a counter that increments and displays the count for each line of data.
For example:
    
    `$count=0;
    echo "index | id | name | section<br />\n";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $id = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['name'];
      $section = $row['section'];
      $count++;
      echo $count." | ".$id." | ".$name." | ".$section."<br />\n";
    }`

Answer (score -2):

Well you can use this query:

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS index FROM tablename;
```

You'll find the explanation here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/05/05/sql-server-generating-row-number-without-ordering-any-columns/

Comment: Well I used the same query nd I got the result. Please refer the link. It might help you.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() is NOT a mysql function, it's available with oracle or mssql, etc.

Comment: Okay.. I've observed that it works on PostgreSQL as well. :)